# Importing universe

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use OpenAI and I got a import error about universe on Jupyter notebook :

```
import gym
import universe

No module named 'universe'
```

When it comes to working on terminal, it returns this error

```
No module named 'twisted.internet'
```

Then I also had install twisted with pip, I got this next error :

```
No module named 'ujson'
```

and after install ujson, I got a error `No module named 'go_vncdriver'` again.
I think that I will get other error again.
So which way to install is most convenient ?
Could I install all packages at once ?
préferably, using pip install.
I am using OSX and python3.6.

Comment: Have you installed **golang**? brew install golang?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing,

```
pip install go_vncdriver
```

And check again.